# Htaccess 301 redirect forum urls

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect forum and topic links to a new format, without losing there ranking in google.

The situation at this moment:
site.com/forum/32-News  -->forum name
site.com/topic/935-topic-name

**How it needs to be:**
**site.com/board/32-News  -->forum name

site.com/thread/935-topic-name**

I searched on this site and google, but did not found anything that matches my issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forum/(.+)$ /board/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^topic/(.+)$ /thread/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```